# How to get the filename in a Batch script?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, title

I am trying to code a program called "FIGHT!.bat", and I want to make it so that you need to keep the title the same as you downloaded it, otherwise an error message would pop up. But I can't do what I want to do. Here is the code so far:

```
@echo off
if not exist FIGHT!.bat (
cls
echo Sorry, but an error has occured.
echo Redownloading the program or renaming the program can help.
pause
exit
) else (
goto logo
)
:logo
...
```

This is alright, but if another Batch file is called that, then the game itself can be run with a different title, and I don't want that. Is there any way to check the name of the program so that if the name isn't "FIGHT!.bat", do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider changing your question title to something shorter and more straightforward. Like "How to get the filename in a batch script?". Make your question more readable so people can easily understand and help you.

Comment: I've just joined today, and I don't know how to change the title of a question yet!

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can as a new user. A moderator will probably do that. Clarify your question anyway, that will help you getting an answer.

Comment: My question is: Is it possible to use an if or for in Batch, to tell if the name of the program is "FIGHT!.bat"? If it is possible, then how do you do it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: `%0` is a special metavariable which is assigned to the running batch file. You can expand that metavariable as `%~nx0` which is the name and extension of the running batch file, or `%~n0` which is the name only. You could therefore use `If "%~nx0"=="FIGHT!.bat" GoTo logo`, followed by your lines `3`-`7`.

Comment: Thanks, Compo! Now I know! Sorry for the 2-hour late reply. :/